# Find list items in other file

Tags: shell-script, command-line, grep

I have one file with hundreds of unique IP addresses (each on a separate line) from which a bot tries to login to one of our services. I would like to see which of these addresses appear in another logfile.

Should I script this, or is there an ingenious way to do this with a single command in the terminal?

Comment: Look at `grep -f`

Comment: or even `grep -xf`

Comment: See this post: [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash)